# Is the phrase "That settled my choice" idiomatic? Are there better, concise alternatives?

Tags: grammaticality, idioms, synonyms

Please consider the following passage:

> I had to choose between A and B. I preferred the letter A. **So that settled my choice**.

Is the phrase "So that settled my choice" used correctly? Is it idiomatic? Are there better alternatives that are just as concise?

To be perfectly clear, what I mean by "that settled my choice" is "that factor brought about my decision". But that's a bit verbose, so I'd prefer to go with "that settled my choice" provided it is idiomatic.

Thank you.

Comment: *So I chose it.*

Comment: 'That settled it' or 'That decided me' (when the context is clear).

Comment: That settled my choice - Made my decision easier, facilitated my choice between A and B. There's no doubt it's idiomatic. 

Another expression could be - 'So my mind was made up in favor of A.'

Comment: In the example you provided 'That settled my choice" states nothing. Flipping a coin to make a decision for you, or, selecting A because it is a triangle, are examples what you might have made your 'choice' on. You do not state any value preference for A. The phrase usually involves some value driven judgement for selection. *"I had to choose between a blue car and a red car. The red is bright and not a color I'd be comfortable in. That settled my choice."*

Comment: @NormanEdward I see your point, but I don't agree. Your statement is clearer, but clarity isn't necessary. That A was preferred (for whatever reason) is a sufficient logical explanation for why A was chosen over B. Even if you don't *understand* why A was preferred, it doesn't change the fact that it *was* preferred.

Comment: @Jason Bassford Even saying I have a preference for A, relates to' "that settled my choice" agreed. However, the crux of a judgement value being used is critical to that particular phrase. Otherwise, the statement is more accurately, "that is my choice."

Comment: I've never heard this idiom - is it BrE?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's idiomatic. It's not the most common phrase, but I've heard it used and it's understandable.

Some (perhaps more common) alternatives:

> That influenced my decision.
>   My choice was clear.
>   Everything being equal, I went with my preference.
>   I picked the one I liked.

Answer (score -1):

**So be it** [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/so+be+it) an idiom

> This is the way it will be